# Трансляция с нескольких веб камер на сайт

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, трансляция

Добрый день. Появилась необходимость транслировать видеопоток с нескольких веб камер на сайт. Каким образом это сделать через WEB технологии, чтобы данная функция была доступна и на мобильных устройствах? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API